# MVC 4 - Entity Framework, ViewModel and Validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework for a project. I have a **Create Product View** which is strongly-typed with a **ProductViewModel** :

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductCompanies { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9àéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Z0-9àéèêçñ\s-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name !")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9àéèêçñ\s][a-zA-Z0-9àéèêçñ\s-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name !")]        
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I have fields and a dropdown list which regroups some product types (a product is composed of a product type). The thing is, when the desired product type is not available in the dropdown list, I allow the user to create a new one, like this :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.ProductViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create a material";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create a material</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Product type : <a class="product_type" id="product_type_link">Using a new model</a>
        </div>
        <div id= "existing_product_type" class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Product.Id_ProductType, Model.ProductTypes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Id_ProductType)
        </div>
        <div id="new_product_type">
        <div class="editor-label">
            Model : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model, new { maxlength = 50, id = "model" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Company : <a class="company" id="company_link">Using a new company name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="existing_company" class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany, Model.ProductCompanies)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany)
        </div>
        <div id="new_company">
             <div class="editor-label">
                Name : 
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { id = "company_name"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName)
            </div>       
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Price :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.CatalogPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.CatalogPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Purchase date :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.PurchaseDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.PurchaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Serial number :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.SerialNumber, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.SerialNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#product_type_link").click(function () {

                if ($("#new_product_type").css("display") == "block") {

                    $("#new_product_type").css("display", "none");
                    $("#existing_product_type").css("display", "block");
                    $("#product_type_link").text("Using a new model");
                    $("#model").val("");
                    $("#company_name").val("");

                }
                else {
                    $("#new_product_type").css("display", "block");
                    $("#existing_product_type").css("display", "none");
                    $("#product_type_link").text("Using an existing model")
                }
            });

            $("#company_link").click(function () {

                if ($("#new_company").css("display") == "block") {

                    $("#new_company").css("display", "none");
                    $("#existing_company").css("display", "block");
                    $("#company_link").text("Using a new company name");
                    $("#company_name").val("");

                }
                else {
                    $("#new_company").css("display", "block");
                    $("#existing_company").css("display", "none");
                    $("#company_link").text("Using an existing company name")
                }
            });

        });

    </script>

}
```

By doing that, in my action, there is a problem with the ModelState which is not valid. I did several test and I think that the model field (so when the user wants to create a new product type) is the problem : it seems that this field is required (should be optional). Here's my action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel pvm)
{
    var productTypeList = from obj in db.ProductTypes orderby obj.ProductCompany.Name ascending where !((from element in db.VehicleTypes select element.Id_ProductType).Contains(obj.Id_ProductType)) select obj;

    ViewBag.Id_ProductType = new SelectList(productTypeList, "Id_ProductType", "Information", pvm.Product.Id_ProductType);
    pvm.ProductTypes = productTypeList.ToList().Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Information, Value = p.Id_ProductType.ToString() }).ToList();

    ViewBag.Id_ProductCompany = new SelectList(db.ProductCompanies, "Id_ProductCompany", "Name", pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany);
    pvm.ProductCompanies = db.ProductCompanies.ToList().Select(pc => new SelectListItem { Text = pc.Name, Value = pc.Id_ProductCompany.ToString() }).ToList();


    Product product = null;
    ProductType productType = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        ModelStateDictionary errors = Validator.isValid(pvm.Product);

        if (errors.Count > 0)
        {
            ModelState.Merge(errors);
            return View(pvm);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pvm.Model))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pvm.CompanyName))
            {
                ProductCompany productCompany = new ProductCompany()
                {
                    Name = pvm.CompanyName
                };

                productType = new ProductType()
                {
                    Model = pvm.Model,
                    ProductCompany = productCompany
                };

                product = new Product()
                {
                    PurchaseDate = pvm.Product.PurchaseDate,
                    SerialNumber = pvm.Product.SerialNumber,
                    CatalogPrice = pvm.Product.CatalogPrice,
                    ProductType = productType
                };
            }
            else
            {
                productType = new ProductType()
                {
                    Model = pvm.Model,
                    Id_ProductCompany = pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany
                };

                product = new Product()
                {
                    PurchaseDate = pvm.Product.PurchaseDate,
                    SerialNumber = pvm.Product.SerialNumber,
                    CatalogPrice = pvm.Product.CatalogPrice,
                    ProductType = productType
                };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            productType = new ProductType()
            {
                Id_ProductType = pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductType,
                Id_ProductCompany = pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany                    
            };

            product = new Product()
            {
                PurchaseDate = pvm.Product.PurchaseDate,
                SerialNumber = pvm.Product.SerialNumber,
                CatalogPrice = pvm.Product.CatalogPrice,
                ProductType = productType
            };
        }

        db.Products.AddObject(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(pvm);
}
```

EDIT : Here is a screenshot from the debugger. When I check the values, the key [5] is the key which is the problem...

[image: Debug screenshot]

Any idea to make this field optional and then create a new product just by choosing a product type in my dropdown list?

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but I would highly advise renaming that property, as the name Model is used by the framework.  Call it ProductModel or something to make it less confusing.

Comment: Add the creation of the product in a separated form (not nested) to avoid the parent validation and then repopulate the parent dropdownlist with the created product selected.

Comment: Thanks @MystereMan, I did it (but I still have my problem, haha).

Comment: @MaximilianoBecerraBustamante thanks for your answer but the requirement is to centralize the product and the product type so I have to do like this...

Comment: @Traffy , if you try using Data Annotations? you can set "Required" field in your model for each property, if you dont explicit this property (Required) `ModelState.IsValid` not consider validate this property. Data Annotations -> [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Yes I know that. Have a look on the screenshot I've posted. It isn't my ModelName and CompanyName fields which are the problem but the ProductType.Model of my ViewModel.

Comment: mm mvc 4 adds unobstrusive jquery validation by default. once i had validation problem with that. And the Debugger shows [5] ProductType.Model -> in your model you has `public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }` both Capitalized, can that make some noise?
. Im trying to replicate your issue :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29121/discussion-between-traffy-and-maximiliano-becerra-bustamante)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have 3 options:

1) Rewrite your regex to support empty values too

2) Add some properties to your viewmodel (e.g. bool) and write a custom validation attribute (e.g. IfPropertyAThenValidate) or something like that

3) If your ViewModel contains an exisiting product type, ignore the Model property:
e.g.:

```
ModelState modelStateOfModel = ModelState["Model"];

if (modelStateOfModel != null)
{
    modelStateOfModel.Errors.Clear();
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't know why but it is my ProductType object which is the problem. In my model.designer (I'm working with DataBase first), the Model property is set to required.

Comment: Yes, in your case it would be ModelState modelStateOfModel = ModelState["ProductType.Model"]; => And you create the new product type on server side BEFORE you save the entity